# Excel VBA - select a range including a hidden column

Tags: vba, excel

I have put together this code to select non continuous cells of a table to create a graph (the number of rows of the table varies)

```
Sub graphB()
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow As Long

  Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CF_total")

  LastRow = sht.Range("E2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

  ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

  Set myRange = Union(Range(sht.Cells(2, 5), sht.Cells(LastRow, 5)), Range(sht.Cells(2, 12), sht.Cells(LastRow, 12)))

  ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=myRange
  ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
End Sub
```

But now I have decided to hide column number 12 of the worksheet (which contains the data that I want to plot) and it does not work anymore. Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Comment: [Display hidden worksheet data and empty cells in a chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-hidden-worksheet-data-and-empty-cells-in-a-chart-A1EE6F0C-192F-4248-ABEB-9CA49CB92274)

Comment: Thank you!! That's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

The VBA for that is,

```
ActiveChart.PlotVisibleOnly = False
```

See [Chart.PlotVisibleOnly Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840090.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more.